# Eureka/Discovery Service vs. Routes

Tags: java, architecture, microservices, cloud-foundry

In CloudFoundry you can access other microservices by registering them in a discovery service and query them by their name. But you can also setup a route ("subdomain"), from which you can call the service, that seems to be quite easier to handle. In both cases clustering, circuit breaker and such can be used.

In which case should one want to use the first or the second approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A registry approach would be preferable when you are concerned about your software's maintainability and resilience.

A registry name can be meaningful to your software's problem domain, and it can be reused across all deployments of your software (dev, qa, prod, etc.)

A route name introduces dependencies on your network infrastructure. It must be globally unique, you need to configure and manage a different one for each deployment of your software, and it can break due to external concerns (example: your subdomain changes due to a company name change).

Comment: There is a third option with newer CF versions - the `apps.internal` domain: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes. This can give you the benefits of a registry that @corbypage stated (logical names and not being affected by changes to external domains) without the need for a separate registry, but is limited to communication between apps running in the same CF foundation.